# JSFiddle does Javascript correctly, but not on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, jsfiddle

I've tested a Javascript on JSFiddle for a localStorage-working textarea. Once I make the HTML page and load it up, it doesn't use the Javascript written.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($) {
    var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
    if (window.localStorage["TextEditorData"]) {
        editor.value = window.localStorage["TextEditorData"];
    }    
    editor.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    window.localStorage["TextEditorData"] = editor.value;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad=".ready()">
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I miss? Testing it on JSFiddle works correctly.

Comment: Are you using a webserver, or just are you just double-clicking the file?

Comment: `onLoad=".ready()"` is a syntax error in JS. Might or might not be related to the problem.

Comment: What I don't get here, is where the ready() function comes from? Its no where declared in your code snippet in your question. Please format your code better, before you post it here.

Comment: Check jsFiddle FAQ http://doc.jsfiddle.net/faq.html#code-is-working-on-jsfiddle-not-on-site-local-machine

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code on a webserver that I installed on my local machine.  A few tests revealed what appeared to be the cause of your woes..  A missing pair of closing brackets:

```
});
```

This closes your `jQuery(function($) {` call above, and your code then works fine for me.  Of course, I also removed that errant `onload=".ready()"` call.

Comment: Same result. Is that the only thing changed?

Comment: @alzonajeremy I changed two things, if you read my answer again.